# URLSession & JSONSerialization Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3, urlsession

Before you read this, please understand that I'm somewhat a beginner with Swift and I'm trying to learn. I've browse through some sites in hope of getting answer but I either can't find or do it incorrectly.. I've been following this tutorial but this is old and not updated >>[Tutorial I followed](http://www.myplacesandme.com/wordpress/swift-app-tutorial-swiftstocks-tuples-switch-singleton-webservices-part-ii/)<<

I also tried to modified some to swift 3 - though I probably didn't do it right.

How do I exactly do the URLSession correctly? I get this error:

> invalid conversion from throwing function of type'(_, _, _) throws ->
>   Void' to non-throwing function type

for this line below:

> let task : URLSessionDataTask = session.dataTask(with: request,
>   completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in

and for the variable "jsonDict" - I get error that I have

> extra arg 'error' in call.

Thanks in advance

```
var urlString:String = ("http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select * from yahoo.finance.quotes where symbol IN "+stringQuotes+"&format=json&env=http://datatables.org/alltables.env").addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlHostAllowed)!

    var url : URL = URL(string: urlString)!
    var request: URLRequest = URLRequest(url:url)
    let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    let session = URLSession(configuration: config)

    let task : URLSessionDataTask = session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in

        if((error) != nil) {
            println(error.localizedDescription)
        }
        else {
            var err: NSError?

            var jsonDict = try JSONSerialization.JSONObject(with: data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers, error: &err) as NSDictionary
            if(err != nil) {
                println("JSON Error \(err!.localizedDescription)")
            }
            else {
                var quotes:NSArray = ((jsonDict.objectForKey("query") as NSDictionary).objectForKey("results") as NSDictionary).objectForKey("quote") as NSArray
                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                    .default.post(name: Notification.Name(rawValue: kNotificationStocksUpdated), object: nil, userInfo: [kNotificationStocksUpdated:quotes])
                })
            }
        }
    })
    task.resume()
}
```

Comment: its should be `var jsonDict = try JSONSerialization.JSONObject(with: data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as NSDictionary` ,in swift 3 error argument removed

Comment: @Vinodh - Thanks, I didn't think it'd be that simple.

Comment: Post it as a answer it will helpful for others

Comment: It's not exactly done yet - still having issue with URLSessionDataTask

Comment: Give some time i will fix above code and post you a answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find the updated code for Swift 3.0

```
var urlString:String = ("http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select * from yahoo.finance.quotes where symbol IN "+stringQuotes+"&format=json&env=http://datatables.org/alltables.env").addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlFragmentAllowed)!

        let url : URL = URL(string: urlString)!
        let request: URLRequest = URLRequest(url:url)
        let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        let session = URLSession(configuration: config)

        let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in

            if(error != nil){
                print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "")
            }
            else{
                do{
                    let jsonDict:NSDictionary = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as! NSDictionary
                    let quotes:NSArray = ((jsonDict.object(forKey: "query") as! NSDictionary).object(forKey: "results") as! NSDictionary).object(forKey: "quote") as! NSArray
                    print(quotes)

                }
                catch{
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
            }
        };
        task.resume()
```

**Note:** I haven't tested the code . Since you haven't  specified the arguments of URL

Comment: seems that fixed it, I think. Thanks! and when you mean by arguments of URL... like this ? `/http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select * from yahoo.finance.quotes where symbol IN ("AAPL","GOOG","FB")&format=json&env=http://datatables.org/alltables.env`

Comment: yes you are correct i don't know what you are passing in 'stringQuotes', now you mentioned in the comment . thanks

Comment: one more change i added url encoding method should be `urlFragmentAllowed` not `urlHostAllowed`, if i use `urlHostAllowed` am unable to reach yahoo api

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not in the `URLSessionDataTask` but in your `completionHandler`. More specifically in the `var jsonDict = try JSONSerialization...` bit. `try` indicates that your code can throw an exception but you don't handle it (`catch`). That's why compiler decides that your completion handler is of the type `(_, _, _) throws -> Void` while `dataTask` method expects `(_, _, _) -> Void`.

[Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ErrorHandling.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH42-ID508) you can find information how to use `try/catch`.

Comment: I tried to but I kept making error, which is why I'm here asking for help.
The orginal code for URLSession is this **let task : NSURLSessionDataTask = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in**

Comment: that solved the problem for me
`
do{
var josnDict = try JSONSer...
...
})
} catch {
//handle error
}
`